# Angular Static File Download

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, html

I'm trying to create a file download or view button using Angular. The file is the same for every user, and I'm hoping to avoid a call to the backend by placing the static file in the frontend.

Most solutions require use of the "download" attribute, which is not very browser compatible ([CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=download)), or they fetch a generated file from the server. I simply want to allow the user to open or download a static pdf file.

I tried a link like this:

```
<a href="/attachment.pdf" target="_self" >Attachment</a>
```

but that looks for a backend link that I obviously do not have. Rather than creating a backend route, I just want to serve the static file.

Is this possible? I have an Angular frontend and Django backend.

Comment: What do you mean by `placing the static file in the frontend` ? What will source be? Take a look at `jspdf.js` library

Comment: I mean that I'd like to have the pdf file stored in the frontend file, with all of my templates, controllers, etc. This way, I wouldn't have to access the backend to get it.

Comment: But your file will have to be stored in your server, i.e. the backend, and then downloaded by the client. What am I not getting here?

Comment: I think I'm confused about the fact that it is not possible for the frontend to access its own current working directory, navigate to files, etc. This kind of operation must be done on the server

Comment: If it's an actual pdf file concept isn't making any sense. It has to come from server somehow and it's not clear at all what you are trying to circumvent

Comment: @ritmatter you can actually try to store the file in your LocalStorage when you are loading your page . Maybe you can then fetch it from there. I'm not sure about this. But just an idea you can try out.

Comment: Directory for front end files doesn't mean files aren't sent from server, unless you are using a build tool to concatenate them and include them in one file. But those would be html not pdf. Look in your dev tools network tab

Comment: @ritmatter The frontend has no 'current working directory'. All assets loaded on a page are sent from the server. What the frontend does with those assets once they're loaded is up to you. You will have to place your PDF file somewhere available on your server, and make a route in your Django app to decide what to do when that route is hit (in this case, deliver the static PDF file).

Answer (score 0):

If what you try to do is concatenate the pdf file along with the javascript code of your angular application, I don't think that is possible (or at least I don't know how to do it nor I think it would be a good idea/ worth it).

Your could serve your pdf file as any other static file, so that you access it by making your users go the file's url, like:

```
<a href="/static/files/myfile.pdf" target="_self" >Attachment</a>
```

That, however, will make the browser decide how to access the pdf file. For example, Chrome by default opens a "preview page".

If you want to force the file to be downloaded to the user's device instead of allowing previews, you need to make your backend do so by setting the `Content-Disposition` header in the response.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.pdf"
```

Comment: Does angular need to do anything special with the response for the download to work?

Comment: Angular shouldn't need to do anything, that would be the browser's responsibility

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the comments on my question, fetching a PDF from the frontend is not possible. I ended up making a backend route for fetching the PDF and then opening it in a new tab. Here is the code I used.

Clickable link that fetches the file from the server:

```
<a ng-click="viewFile()" href="">Attachment</a>
```

Function that hits backend route:

```
$scope.viewFile = function() {
  var downloadFileURL = $rootScope.urlFormatter2('file');
  $http.get(downloadFileURL, {responseType:'arraybuffer'})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      window.open(fileURL);
    })
    .error(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

Backend route (in Django):

```
def ctm_file(request):
    filename = "ctm_form.pdf" # Select your file here.
    wrapper = FileWrapper(file(filename))
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return response
```

Thanks to everyone for helping better understand the nature of fetching files with a client server application.

Comment: what's the point? Why not just open the url without all the unnecessary code? Path is still detectable using dev tools network so you aren't masking anything

Comment: I'm not trying to mask anything, I just wanted a really simple way to serve the pdf file and display it. I don't see how I could have served the file from the server in a simpler way or displayed it in the frontend without creating a blob.

Comment: `window.open('/attachment.pdf')`

Comment: When I just put in a route like that, Django assumes that I am trying to use a predefined backend route. The way to fix that issue was to actually create the backend route and serve the pdf. It doesn't let me arbitrarily fetch files like that.

Comment: well whatever works. I assumed was static asset file as was mentioned in question